# why do I see different results for www and non-www version of my blog in django/Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am using django/mezzanine 4.3.0 as my blog engine.

In the non-www version of my site, everything is okay. But when I enter the domain with www, I only see the right panel (which is a static code) and the footer. 
Everything that is derived from the database is not there.

When I log-in to admin panel, on the top bar I can choose between the available sites, when I choose the www version and I navigate to blogs, pages, etc, there are nothing there.

What is the problem? What have I done wrong?

Can it be due to the following line in local_settings.py??

"DOMAINS": ["myblog.com", "www.myblog.com"]

Comment: If you want to aim both  addresses to the same content you should catch that in the configuration of your web address. Otherwise you have to enter in twice.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? How do I catch that and in which configuration?

Comment: myblog.com and www.myblog.com are different web addresses. If your goal is for them to point to the same IP address someone has to take care of that. This has to happen above the django level.  At least that would be the correct way. You could also redirect on the django level but that will mean if you enter www.myblog.com you will be redirected to myblog.com. The domain list in settings is just for safety which domains are allowed.